# Mathematica on Chromebook?

Tags: interoperability, installation

I'm thinking of getting a touchscreen Chromebook, is there any way to run or install desktop Mathematica on it?

Comment: No. Use Mathematica Online.

Comment: For my purposes, Mathematica online is a nonstarter. Completely and totally unstable for long running or memory intensive applications, IMO it shouldn't be released, but in private alpha.

Comment: Well, the whole idea of the Chromebook is to substitute webapps for desktop apps. Perhaps the Chromebook is not the right choice for you.